# Calling external php function in <img>

Tags: php, html, image

I've created an external php file (sort.php) that sorts the files in a folder on the server by time modified, and returns the most recent file.

```
<?php

function scanDir ($dir){

    $fileTimeArray = array();

    // Scan directory and get each file date
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $fileTime){
        $fileTimeArray[$fileTime] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $fileTime);  
    }

    //Sort file times
    var $latestFile = arsort($fileTimeArray);

    return($latestFile[0]);
}

?>
```

I'm attempting to call this function inside of , in another php file, and set the src:

```
<img <?php echo 'src="'.scanDir("issues/preview").'"';?>/>
```

I've included sort.php at the top of the page in question.

The image src reads "(unknown)". What am I missing or doing wrong or both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write

```
<?php $x = scanDir("issues/preview"); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $x; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Johannes! This solved referencing the function in the <img>! Looks like there's a problem with my function as src now reads "Array."